# Qual é a vida útil de um cartão SD com Raspbian (Raspberry Pi)?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Como todos usuários do Raspberry Pi devem saber, o sistema operacional roda a partir do cartão SD.

Isso pode resultar em um problema, porque se o cartão for escrito muitas vezes constantemente, vai reduzir a vida útil do SD para bem pouco tempo. Se me lembro bem, a Memória Flash geralmente tem uma expectativa de apenas umas 10.000 operações de escrita.

Bom, com isso gostaria de saber se o Raspbian faz escritas no cartão SD mesmo quando esta ocioso.

E caso tenha alguma operação, talvez de log, como posso desativar essa operação que esta comprometendo a vida útil do SD?

Estou fazendo um projeto que nunca (espera-se!) seja desligado.

Já tenho um sistema com microcontrolador PIC, e neste nem a memoria EEPROM está sendo escrita por esse motivo. Porém o PIC não tem capacidade para as novas solicitações de operações.

Encontrei uma resposta para Debian, mas está desatualizada para Raspbian:

> #### [Tips for running Linux on a flash device by David Härdeman](http://www.cyrius.com/debian/nslu2/linux-on-flash/)
>
> `<david@hardeman.nu>`
>
> If you are running your NSLU2 on a USB flash key, there are a number
>   of things you might want to do in order to reduce the wear and tear on
>   the underlying flash device (as it only supports a limited number of
>   writes).
>
> Note: this document currently describes Debian etch (4.0) and needs to
>   be updated to Debian squeeze (6.0) and Debian wheezy (7.0). Some of
>   the hints may still apply, but some may not.
>
> The ext3 filesystem per default writes metadata changes every five
>   seconds to disk. This can be increased by mounting the root filesystem
>   with the `commit=N` parameter which tells the kernel to delay writes to
>   every N seconds.
>
> The kernel writes a new atime for each file that has been read which
>   generates one write for each read. This can be disabled by mounting
>   the filesystem with the `noatime` option.
>
> Both of the above can be done by adding e.g. `noatime,commit=120,...` to
>   `/etc/fstab`. This can also be done on an already mounted filesystem by
>   running the command:
>
> ```
> mount -o remount,noatime,commit=120 /
> ```
>
> The system will run updatedb every day which creates a database of all
>   files on the system for use with the locate command. This will also
>   put some stress on the filesystem, so you might want to disable it by
>   adding
>
> ```
> exit 0
> ```
>
> early in the `/etc/cron.daily/find` script. syslogd will in the default
>   installation sync a lot of log files to disk directly after logging
>   some new information. You might want to change `/etc/syslog.conf` so
>   that every filename starts with a `-` (minus) which means that writes
>   are not synced immediately (which increases the risk that some log
>   messages are lost if your system crashes). For example, a line such
>   as:
>
> ```
> kern.*                          /var/log/kern.log
> ```
>
> would be changed to:
>
> ```
> kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
> ```
>
> You also might want to disable some classes of messages altogether by
>   logging them to `/dev/null` instead, see syslog.conf(5) for details.
>
> In addition, syslogd likes to write `-- MARK --` lines to log files
>   every 20 minutes to show that syslog is still running. This can be
>   disabled by changing SYSLOGD in `/etc/default/syslogd` so that it reads
>
> ```
> SYSLOGD="-m 0"
> ```
>
> After you've made any changes, you need to restart syslogd by running
>
> ```
> /etc/init.d/syslogd restart
> ```
>
> If you have a swap partition or swap file on the flash device, you
>   might want to move it to a different part of the disk every now and
>   then to make sure that different parts of the disk gets hit by the
>   frequent writes that it can generate. For a swap file this can be done
>   by creating a new swap file before you remove the old one.
>
> If you have a swap partition or swap file stored on the flash device,
>   you can make sure that it is used as little as possible by setting
>   `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` to zero.
>
> The kernel also has a setting known as laptop_mode, which makes it
>   delay writes to disk (initially intended to allow laptop disks to spin
>   down while not in use, hence the name). A number of files under
>   `/proc/sys/vm/` controls how this works:
>
> `/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode`: How many seconds after a read should a
>   writeout of changed files start (this is based on the assumption that
>   a read will cause an otherwise spun down disk to spin up again).
>
> `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs`: How often the kernel should
>   check if there is "dirty" (changed) data to write out to disk (in
>   centiseconds).
>
> `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs`: How old "dirty" data should be
>   before the kernel considers it old enough to be written to disk. It is
>   in general a good idea to set this to the same value as
>   `dirty_writeback_centisecs` above.
>
> `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio`: The maximum amount of memory (in percent) to
>   be used to store dirty data before the process that generates the data
>   will be forced to write it out. Setting this to a high value should
>   not be a problem as writeouts will also occur if the system is low on
>   memory.
>
> `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio`: The lower amount of memory (in
>   percent) where a writeout of dirty data to disk is allowed to stop.
>   This should be quite a bit lower than the above `dirty_ratio` to allow
>   the kernel to write out chunks of dirty data in one go.
>
> All of the above kernel parameters can be tuned by using a custom init
>   script, such as this example script. Store it to e.g.
>   `/etc/init.d/kernel-params`, make it executable with
>
> ```
> chmod a+x /etc/init.d/kernel-params
> ```
>
> and make sure it is executed by running
>
> ```
> update-rc.d kernel-params defaults
> ```
>
> Note: Most of these settings reduce the number of writes to disk by
>   increasing memory usage. This increases the risk for out of memory
>   situations (which can trigger the dreaded OOM killer in the kernel).
>   This can even happen when there is free memory available (for example
>   when the kernel needs to allocate more than one contiguous page and
>   there are only fragmented free pages available).
>
> As with any tweaks, you are advised to keep a close eye on the amount
>   of free memory and adapt the tweaks (e.g. by using less aggressive
>   caching and increasing the swappiness) depending on your workload.

Comment: A restrição de tempo para se responder à própria pergunta (que acredito valer só para usuários novos) é para evitar abusos ou erros comuns - por exemplo para que o autor [que ainda não está familiarizado com a plataforma] tente continuar acrescentando conteúdo na forma de um fórum (i.e. vários posts, em vez de editar sua pergunta). Mas basta uns dois votos a favor para você [eliminar esta (e outras) restrições](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user).

Comment: Ok, obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 9):

Acredito que isso seja muito relativo.

Uma memória flash tem aproximadamente um tempo de vida de 10.000 (dez mil) a 1.000.000 (um milhão) de ciclos de escrita (perceba que este valor tem um "range" muito grande). Entretanto, isto pode variar muito de fabricante para fabricante e, inclusive, pode variar com as condições que o hardware é exposto.

Também é bastante complicado de mapear todas as operações de escrita que o sistema operacional faz (neste caso, Linux) e quantificá-las, principalmente para efetuar um cálculo do tempo de vida. Tudo o que falarem a respeito disto é especulação, porque é uma tarefa muito complexa mapear tudo o que está acontecendo no sistema operacional.

O que você pode fazer é se basear no tempo de vida de smartphones com Android. O sistema operacional é baseado em Linux e funciona de forma bastante semelhante ao Raspbian. Também utilizamos cartões SD nos smartphones.

O sistema operacional faz operações de leitura e escrita de uma forma muito frequente. Lembre-se que "tudo é um arquivo". Mas durante a inicialização, boa parte do conteúdo destes arquivos é alocado na Memória RAM. Tenha certeza que, o sistema operacional fará operações de escrita quando você instalar algum programa, fazer configurações, criar arquivos, editar arquivos, manipular um banco de dados. Também pode acontecer de o sistema operacional fazer uma operação de escrita simplesmente para mudar uma flag ou configuração de algum arquivo. É imprevisível dizer quando o sistema fará isto, pois existem milhares de programas sendo executados. E quanto ao Raspbian estar "ocioso", isso também é muito relativo. Aparentemente ele pode não estar executando nenhum programa, mas o sistema está executando milhares de tarefas que entram e saem de contexto diversas vezes em um único segundo! As entradas e saídas de contexto utilizam a Memória RAM e o cache do processador, porém durante a entrada e saída de contexto, pode acontecer de faltar Memória RAM e o sistema utilizar o cartão SD como memória virtual (swap), neste caso temos outra operação de escrita no SD.

A questão que você levantou foi bastante interessante, mas creio que não há uma resposta absoluta, e creio que seja impossível que seu Raspberry consiga ficar  "eternamente ligado".

Alguns fabricantes de cartões SD garantem um período de vida de 5 anos. Então duvido que ele dure mais do que isto. Mesmo que você faça operações mínimas de leitura e escrita, um cartão SD não foi desenvolvido para durar para sempre, ainda mais estando constantemente ligado. Existem inúmeros fatores que causam a diminuição da vida útil como umidade, calor, luz e até mesmo obsolescência programada! Pois cartões SD possuem um microcontrolador interno, responsável por fazer comunicação do tipo SPI, portanto, ele pode ter sido facilmente programado para depois de uma quantidade de operações de leitura/escrita ser totalmente inútil.

Recomendo que veja com o fabricante o período de vida do cartão, evite fazer muitas operações de escrita, mapeando alguns dos pontos que citei, e não espere muito mais do que 5 anos para o seu cartão SD. É possível remover os logs do sistema operacional e milhares de outras coisas que possam estar escrevendo no cartão, porém o sistema foi projetado desta forma e isso pode causar mal funcionamento e travar sua aplicação, além de ser uma tarefa dificílima, pois você terá que fazer muitas modificações em diversos arquivos.

**Editado:**

Encontrei [este artigo](http://www.zdnet.com/raspberry-pi-extending-the-life-of-the-sd-card-7000025556/) contendo algumas dicas reais de como aumentar a vida do seu cartão SD com Raspbian. A que mais me chamou a atenção foi: "Colocar o cartão SD como somente leitura", desta forma existe uma garantia a nível de hardware que o seu cartão não será escrito. Porém, como o próprio autor do texto afirma, existem algumas desvantagens e é preciso muito trabalho para configurar o Sistema Operacional para que trabalhe desta forma. Além de que, todas as alterações que o sistema fizer não poderão ser salvas.

Sugiro que compre um cartão SD de uma marca conhecida, com uma taxa de transferência bem grande (um classe 10 já é uma boa), pois, independente do tempo de vida do cartão, seu Raspbian vai trabalhar melhor. E comprar um cartão com uma quantidade de armazenamento maior (o Raspbian só suporta até 32Gb) vai aumentar o período de vida pois existirá uma área maior para ser escrita.

Outra dica importante que li no [artigo](http://www.zdnet.com/raspberry-pi-extending-the-life-of-the-sd-card-7000025556/) é utilizar o "tmpfs", que é um recurso que permite escrever na memória RAM como se fosse um sistema de arquivos comum. Com isso você vai economizar nas escritas no SD, o que pode fazer (veja que isso é apenas uma especulação) com que a vida útil aumente. Tenha cuidado com este recurso, calcule que programas vão ser executados e não deixe o sistema sem espaço na memória RAM.

Comment: Complementando: o cartão SD utiliza SPI para comunicação e não I2C, também pode ocorrer de o sistema operacional utilizar outro tipo de comunicação direta com o cartão SD.

Comment: Obrigado pela correção! Realmente... eu me confundi. MOSI, MISO, SCK, RST,VCC e GND. =)

Comment: @Avelino, nos ambientes *nix e todos os seus sabores, quando se diz que tudo é um arquivo, não necessariamente significa que tudo será escrito no sistema de armazenamento para ser depois lido, portanto o fato de existir tal representação no sistema de arquivos, apenas diz que tal recurso pode ser acessado de forma semelhante a arquivos, e que a respectiva API pode ser usada.

Answer (score 5):

Em resumo: não se incomode com isto.

As 10.000 ou 100.000 operações de escrita contam por célula de 512 bytes, mas o próprio circuito do SD card alterna o uso das células para que todas "gastem" igualmente. Além disso, estas são as garantias mínimas -- a maioria das células dura bem mais que isto e cartões de boas marcas têm células de reserva para compensar as primeiras falhas.

Isto se traduz numa vida útil bastante longa, provavelmente mais longa que um HD. O cartão vai estragar por "causas naturais" (por menos que seja utilizado, pendrive ou SD card parece não durar mais que 5 anos, pois é muito sensível a estática ou mesmo um bom tombo) ou mais provavelmente você vai trocá-lo por um cartão maior.

A única possível exceção é se você estiver rodando algum programa que grave dados na velocidade máxima, o tempo todo. Mesmo assim, vai demorar. Gravar 8GB por 100.000 vezes vai demorar meses, isto são 800TB. Que caso de uso gera tantos dados?

Se quiser realmente "caprichar":

1) Unix/Linux registra (grava) a data da última LEITURA de um arquivo. Montar o sistema de arquivos com "noatime" evita esta gravação, o que alivia o SD Card e é quase sempre indicado em sistemas embarcados por questões de performance. Antigamente era costume fazer isso até em Linux doméstico. Provavelmente a distribuição Linux que você usa para o Rasbpberry já faz isto.

2) A marca do cartão SD faz diferença. Se deseja muita confiabilidade, compre de boas marcas.

3) Use um cartão SD maior, dividindo o desgaste entre mais células. Só vale a pena se você realmente espera gravar muitos dados o tempo todo e.g. o Raspberry controlando câmeras de vigilância, ou usando muito swap.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, estou com esta dúvida, porque eu já projetei um circuito para Horímetro digital com microcontrolador PIC, no qual havia necessidade de gravar a memória EEPROM a cada 1 segundo, o que faria com que a duração da memória fosse degradada em menos de 15 dias! E para o caso eu utilizei um sistema incremental de gravação a fim de não escrever a mesma célula seguidamente, que assegurava (teoricamente) uma duração de vários anos!

Comment: Quanto ao fato de o sistema operacional fazer registro de quase todas operações, isso explica a degradação mais intensa nos sistemas operacionais atuais, o que é cada vez mais perceptível, quando o usuário pede para um programa abrir e o programa não abre, mas o indicador de atividade do HDD fica piscando com intervalos seguidos, cheguei a essa conclusão porque eu já tive vários HDD com bad blocks e o sintoma é sempre esse.

Comment: Já para o caso de deixar o Raspberry sempre ligado, sim essa é a necessidade, porque é o que se espera de um controlador para um relógio (de torre de Igreja) o que espera-se é uma longa duração do sistema sem necessidade de manutenções corretivas constantes. Essa ideia de deixar o cartão SD para apenas leitura é muito interessante, o que passa a fazer uma certa assimilação de modo de funcionamento com os microcontroladores mais simples, que aliás tem uma impressionante e estável duração!

Comment: Quem conhece os 8051, pode dizer um pouco sobre isso, já consertei diversos aparelhos com este e outros tipos de microcontroladores antigos, mas geralmente o defeito nunca era no uC.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma outra sugestão de instalação em sistema somente leitura, mas também não é para Raspbian, talvez isso possa servir de exemplo para que alguém possa contribuir com alguma dica orientada ao Raspbian:

```
Howto: Install readonly emdebian on NAND
(http://forum.doozan.com/read.php?2,72)

I've done some preliminary work getting debian installed to the NAND:

The installation is, by default, readonly. The installer includes a few workarounds to make everything work from the readonly filesystem. It creates a /sbin/init-ro script to mount and initialize a few tmpfs mount points. My goal is to keep the root system readonly, with all read-write parts located on tmpfs, NFS, or external drive.

You can add extra packages by modifying the variables at the top of the installer, or by remounting the system read-write and running apt. By default, this install will only install packages from embdebian. If you need to install packages from the full Debian, you'll need to add a repository to /etc/apt/sources.list. Be aware, however, that the package list itself is over 30M.

If you would prefer to make it read-write, just 'mount -o remount,rw'. You can edit /etc/fstab and remove the 'ro' from the root mount make the system permanently read-write.

The default install is 112M uncompressed on ext2 and 72M compressed on UBIFS.

I welcome any comments and suggestions on improving this.

-- Jeff

Remove USB drive, boot into pogoplug
Attach your USB drive, partition it with fdisk, and then run the following commands: 


cd /tmp
wget http://jeff.doozan.com/debian/dockstar.emdebian-squeeze-readonly.sh
chmod +x dockstar.emdebian-squeeze-readonly.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin
./dockstar.emdebian-squeeze-readonly.sh


Reboot into Debian
Create UBIFS on mtd3 using the following commands: 


flash_eraseall /dev/mtd3
ubiformat /dev/mtd3 -y
ubiattach /dev/ubi_ctrl -m 3
ubimkvol /dev/ubi0 -m -N rootfs


Copy system to ubifs 


mkdir /tmp/ubifs
mount -t ubifs ubi0:rootfs /tmp/ubifs

tar \
--exclude=/lost+found  \
--exclude=/tmp  \
--exclude=/sys  \
--exclude=/proc \
-cf - / | ( cd /tmp/ubifs ; tar -xpvf - )
mkdir /tmp/ubifs/tmp
mkdir /tmp/ubifs/sys
mkdir /tmp/ubifs/proc

# change root fs type from ext2 to ubifs
sed -i 's/^\(\/dev\/root.*\)ext2/\1ubifs/' /tmp/ubifs/etc/fstab > /dev/null 2>&1
umount /tmp/ubifs


Configure UBIFS booting 


fw_setenv set_bootargs_ubi 'setenv bootargs console=$console ubi.mtd=3 root=ubi0:rootfs rootfstype=ubifs $mtdparts init=/sbin/init-ro'
fw_setenv bootcmd_ubi 'run set_bootargs_ubi; ubi part data; ubifsmount rootfs; ubifsload 0x800000 /boot/uImage; ubifsload 0x1100000 /boot/uInitrd; bootm 0x800000 0x1100000'

# Configure new bootloader to run old uBoot
fw_setenv bootcmd 'run bootcmd_ubi; run bootcmd_usb; run bootcmd_pogo; reset'


Remove your USB drive and reboot into Debian on NAND


NOTE: If you change your UBIFS root to read-only (to edit files or install packages) and lose power or crash before you remount it a read-only, uBoot will think the partition has errors and will refuse to boot from it. In that case, it will try booting from USB. If there are no bootable USB devices, it will boot the original Pogoplug installation. From there, you can mount and unmount the UBIFS partition, just to reset the 'dirty' flags and uBoot will be okay again.
```